# how does Passport.js obtains the Profile data using OAuth2 strategy?

Tags: facebook, oauth, passport.js

In the [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) of oauth2 strategy usage in the Passport's repo, the following function is presented:

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

How does Passport obtains the `profile` field? is it provided with the token by the oauth endpoint? or does it come from a separate (session-related) request?

When using, for example, the Facebook's oauth API, the user info is loaded *automatically* with the Passport's Facebook strategy, so I'm trying to figure out how does this happen and how to implement a similar behavior in a custom oauth2 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user profile is typically loaded after the `access_token` is successfully retrieved:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L175

```
 this._oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(code, { grant_type: 'authorization_code', redirect_uri: callbackURL  },
      function(err, accessToken, refreshToken, params) {
        if (err) { return self.error(self._createOAuthError('Failed to obtain access token', err)); }

        self._loadUserProfile(accessToken, function(err, profile) {
          if (err) { return self.error(err); }
```

The function to actually get the user information is often provided by the specific strategy (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, etc)

In Facebook's implementation:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L137